# QTextEdit box not sizing to QMainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.7

MY UI ISSUE

[image]

It is not covering the window and I don't know why. I am making a text editor.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, qApp, QMenu, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QMenuBar, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()


    def _createMenuBar(self):
        self.statusBar()
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        mainMenu.setNativeMenuBar(False)

        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('File')
        editMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Edit')
        viewMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('View')
        searchMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Search')
        toolsMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Tools')
        helpMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Help')


    def _createTextArea(self):
        textEdit = QTextEdit(self)


    def initUI(self):
        self._createMenuBar()
        self._createTextArea()

        exitAct = QAction(QIcon('media/img/funcs/exit-img.png'), 'Exit', self)
        exitAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAct.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')
        self.toolbar.addAction(exitAct)

        self.setGeometry(100, 95, 600, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Hawk - Editor')
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have read the documentation. However I dont know what i have missed.
I have also included an image of the UI problem.

Comment: Sorry to be a bit blunt, but you say "I have read the documentation", and the reason of your issue is clearly specified in the [*introduction* to QMainWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#details): "Creating a main window without a central widget is not supported. You must have a central widget even if it is just a placeholder."

Answer (score 1):

QMainWindow has a predefined structure as shown in [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework):

[image]

On the other hand, a widget will be drawn on top of the parent, so when you pass the QTextEdit to the QMainWindow as parent you see that problem. A possible solution is to create a centralWidget and pass it as parent to QTextEdit:

```py
def _createTextArea(self):
    textEdit = QTextEdit(self.central_widget)
```

```py
def initUI(self):
    self.central_widget = QWidget()
    self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
    self._createMenuBar()
    self._createTextArea()
    # ...
```

Another solution is to set QTextEdit as centralWidget:

```py
def _createTextArea(self):
    textEdit = QTextEdit()
    self.setCentralWidget(textEdit)
```

Comment: @TysonBoring then please read [ask] and review the [tour]